# How to create a button that marks user as "Going" to Facebook event using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I want to create a button on my site using PHP that marks users as "Going" to a Facebook event that click the button.

This is the PHP SDK that Facebook has for attending:

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
  '/{event-id}/attending',
  '{access-token}'
   );
 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
   }
   $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    /* handle the result */
```

Also where it says:

```
/* make the API call */
```

Does that mean I need to put this?

```
   GET graph.facebook.com/{node-id}
```

Is node id the same as the event id in this case?

Do I simply need to create a form with a button that submits to a PHP file containing this code? Like let's say I had the form with an action that was "myurl.com/attending.php" and inside "attending.php" was this Facebook PHP SDK with the appropriate variables. Also the form has the method="GET". Would this work?

I'm sorry for the very open ended question without much/any of my own code, but I am really our of my depth here and looking for some help. I'm not familiar with Facebook Graph API or any HTTP-based API's for that matter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First the user need to use Facebook Login. Then grant you the right permissions. Then you can use that API call

Comment: Thanks WizKid! Question: if they click the button, can I just check to see if they are logged in, and if not then bring up a window to have them log in, then once they login do the call? Or if they are logged in then just do the call?